# Vide Plugin [not Video.js] Setting Video as Full Page Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I am using this plugin https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide

It is playing video correctly, but does not set video height as full page. The solution on the link below does not work in my case. If a specific height like 400px is set for the video, it will display the video. If height:100% is set, the video will disappear. It seems that the default height of the video block is 0.

https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide/issues/81

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row" id="video-home" data-vide-bg="{{ MEDIA_URL}}myvideo.mp4" 
data-vide-options="posterType: 'detect', loop: true, muted: true, resizing: true, 
position: 0% 0%, bgColor: 'transparent'">
</div>
```

css styling

```
#video-home {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 400px;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    /*background-size: cover;*/
}
```

Could anyone point to me what to change? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to set HTML and BODY to height:100%; You need to define the parent elements height or is going to collapse.

Comment: thanks. Wait for more solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

I set the position as absolute, and then it works!!!!